# WSO2 API Manager 2.0 Swagger Console not working

Tags: swagger, wso2-api-manager, wso2

We've deployed WSO2 API Manager 2.0 and it's working fine. Although we are facing an issue with the swagger console, which is not loading and returns `Can't read swagger JSON from https://myapimanager.com/store/api-docs/admin/PizzaShackAPI/1.0.0?envName=undefined`.

Although the logs from the server do not show anything, we were able to find the issue. The issue is that when we try to open that web page it gives

`Error 404 : Resource cannot be found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed,had its name changed, is temporarily unavailable or does not exist.`.

Additionally, we've found out that if we only request the page

`https://myapimanager.com/store/api-docs`

it returns

`Error 500 : The page cannot be displayed. The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.`

and the API Manager logs return:

```
    ERROR - WebAppManager org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.secure.AuthorizationFailedException: User wso2.anonymous.user is not authorized to read the resource /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/provider/store//api-docs/swagger.json. (/store/site/blocks/api-doc/ajax/get.jag#90)
org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.secure.AuthorizationFailedException: User wso2.anonymous.user is not authorized to read the resource /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/provider/store//api-docs/swagger.json. (/store/site/blocks/api-doc/ajax/get.jag#90)
      at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:571)
      at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
      at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.exec(WebAppManager.java:588)
      at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:508)
      at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doGet(JaggeryServlet.java:24)
      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:747)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:485)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:377)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:337)
      at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
      at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
      at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
      at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
      at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
      at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
      at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
      at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
      at org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.internal.tenantmgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:48)
      at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
      at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
      at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
      at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
      at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
      at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
      at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1749)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1708)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.secure.AuthorizationFailedException: User wso2.anonymous.user is not authorized to read the resource /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/provider/store//api-docs/swagger.json. (/store/site/blocks/api-doc/ajax/get.jag#90)
      at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.throwAsScriptRuntimeEx(Context.java:1754)
      at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:148)
      at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:225)
      at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
      at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.api_doc.ajax.c0._c_anonymous_1(/store/site/blocks/api-doc/ajax/get.jag:90)
      at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.api_doc.ajax.c0.call(/store/site/blocks/api-doc/ajax/get.jag)
      at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
      at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.api_doc.ajax.c0._c_script_0(/store/site/blocks/api-doc/ajax/get.jag:11)
      at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.api_doc.ajax.c0.call(/store/site/blocks/api-doc/ajax/get.jag)
      at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
      at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
      at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.api_doc.ajax.c0.call(/store/site/blocks/api-doc/ajax/get.jag)
      at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.api_doc.ajax.c0.exec(/store/site/blocks/api-doc/ajax/get.jag)
      at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
      ... 45 more
 Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.secure.AuthorizationFailedException: User wso2.anonymous.user is not authorized to read the resource /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/provider/store//api-docs/swagger.json.
      at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.get(CacheBackedRegistry.java:195)
      at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.getInternal(UserRegistry.java:617)
      at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.access$400(UserRegistry.java:61)
      at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$5.run(UserRegistry.java:597)
      at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$5.run(UserRegistry.java:594)
      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
      at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.get(UserRegistry.java:594)
      at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.get(UserRegistry.java:61)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
      at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
      ... 57 more
```

As you can see, it logs something about an anonymous user which is trying to access but has no permissions.

Swagger is a great feature to have in the API Description and we would like to keep it.

Thanks in advance!
Best Regards

Comment: Have you fronted APIM by an LB or reverse proxy? Looks like the issue is related to something like that.

Comment: Yes, we do have nginx. We followed this tutorial: http://sanjeewamalalgoda.blogspot.pt/2014/12/configure-wso2-api-manager-with-reverse.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the path of `swagger.json`, there is an extra slash in the middle.

```
/_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/provider/store//api-docs/swagger.json
```

Make sure you have set `proxy_path` for store like this. (No slash at the end)

```
proxy_pass https://localhost:9443/store
```

Similar was experienced [here](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-3926) as well.